# Sql query not part of aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access

when I run the following query in access

```
SELECT SUM(RegBed) AS RegBedTOTAL, PostcodeRESULTS_PostcodeNS as postcode
FROM cooltableless10;
```

I get the following error:

```
this query does not include the specified expression 'postcode' as part of an aggregate function.
```

Could somebody tell me why it is so?

Comment: Try adding `group by PostcodeRESULTS_PostcodeNS` to the end

Comment: Using the Query Builder for these queries, testing them and then viewing the SQL generated behind the scenes is a good way to get up to speed with things like `GROUP BY`, crosstabs and joins.

Answer (score 3):

`SUM` is an aggregate function, which means that any non-aggregated columns must be included in a `GROUP BY` clause.  Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(RegBed) AS RegBedTOTAL, PostcodeRESULTS_PostcodeNS as postcode
FROM cooltableless10
GROUP BY PostcodeRESULTS_PostcodeNS
```

Comment: +1. Better answer than the one I gave, but "postalcode" could be a MS Access Reserved Word, too.

Comment: I get a popup asking me to:
'enter parameter value on postcoderesults_postcodeNS'

Comment: Max F: this error will come up if Access can't find a column name in the table.  Based on the query you supplied, there are (at least) two columns in the `cooltableless10` table: `RegBed` and `PostcodeRESULTS_PostcodeNS`.  Check the spelling of the table names; maybe one or the other was mistyped here?

Comment: Does this version work? `SELECT SUM(RegBed) AS RegBedTOTAL, PostcodeRESULTS_PostcodeNS 
FROM cooltableless10
GROUP BY PostcodeRESULTS_PostcodeNS`

Comment: Please post a screenshot showing your table design/definition.  Alternatively, use Matt Weller's suggestion and build the query directly in the Query Designer (which will prevent any typos from happening by virtue of there being no typing necessary).

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a group by clause 
and group it by postcode
add some like this on your query:

```
group by postcode
```

you always need to add group by clause and group your data when
using aggregate functions on your query